# drawArc() on canvas is causing slow frames

Tags: android, performance, canvas, draw

I created a custom view which is simply using `canvas.drawArc()` to draw a circle like the following:

[image]

This simple drawing command, without any additional commands is already causing slow frames that are reported by the "Android Vitals" section in the play store.

I created a [sample app on github](https://github.com/chriswiesner/DrawArcDemo) to demonstrate the behavior.